# Get a list of all installed apps on Android API 33

Tags: android

Prior to android api 33 we could get a list of all the installed apps by calling:

```
packageManager.queryIntentActivities(i, 0)
```

with this permission in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
```

But in api 33 `queryIntentActivities(intent, int)` has been deprecated. The only option I can find is this

```
queryIntentActivities(chooser, android.content.pm.PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)
```

However the flag `PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY` doesn't not return all apps. So what is the equivalent of the old function to get all apps in android 13?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer myself.

In the manifest only the queries tag is needed, not the permission I put above.

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Then in the code you can get the list of all the launchable apps like this:

```
val allApps = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
    packageManager.queryIntentActivities(i, PackageManager.ResolveInfoFlags.of(PackageManager.MATCH_ALL.toLong()))
} else {
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    packageManager.queryIntentActivities(i, 0)
}
```

Comment: It works, but this lists only pre installed apps. It does not list user installed apps though. It looks like according to google documentation, from Android 11 and higher it won't allow you to list all apps to prevent privacy of a user I guess. Unless there is any special permission requires to list all apps including pre-installed and user installed apps.